# 2 different sets of downlights off the same switch. How to wire?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I am going to be changing a bedroom ceiling rose into 2 different sets of downlights. The first set is the main room lighting and the second is in cabinet lighting. Both of which I would like to switch on using the same room switch.

My question is how best to add the second set of cabinet lights. Should they be added on to the end of the downlights loop or have their own wiring?

I have drawn 2 diagrams showing what I mean.
[image: Second set off the end of the main downlights]
[image: Second Lights off their own wiring]

The two lights in question are the main room lights:
https://www.screwfix.com/p/luceco-ftype-fixed-fire-rated-led-downlight-white-600lm-6w-220-240v/6092t

And some mini downlights:
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3WIndoor-Recessed-LED-Cabinet-Light-Mini-Spotlight-Small-Ceiling-Lamp-Downlight/254407149000?hash=item3b3bd905c8:m:mOo9ZORoSX-ylBP9pHDUgOQ

Comment: Unless there's some specific (UK, I guess from "Ring Main") local rule, should be six on the one hand, half a dozen on the other hand (*i.e.* doesn't matter, either will work fine.)

Answer (score 3):

Ecnerwal make an excellent statement; doesn't matter.

I've got 25 years with the power company designing underground systems for high rise buildings, residential subdivisions and downtown areas. We hate radial feeds because if you have a problem, everyone's out. So I'd be running both sets to the switch. If something goes wrong with a section, you can disconnect that section from the switch and power up the other set so you have lights to fix the problem. (I know, I'm being ridiculous).

Comment: Yup!  Either way will work.  Only thing that concerns me is space in the box for the wires and a UK-legal way to splice the 4 neutrals.